# Samples of illumination level changes in photos for image processing project

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on an OpenCV project and for that I need sample photos of Illumination changes to test my image processing project on, for example:

- The same indoor scene with the lights off and on.
- The same outdoor scene on a sunny day at different times of the day so the light comes from different directions.
- The same outdoor scene both on a cloudy and a sunny day.
- etc.

So basically pairs (or larger sets) of pictures of the same scene, taken from exactly the same position with the same camera, but under different illumination circumstances.

Does anyone know where I can find such sets of samples?

Comment: Hi, I reformulated your question to make it clearer what you are looking form. I hope I understood your request correctly? Perhaps you can edit the set of examples I give to closer match your situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look in several image databases like http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/root_files_V3/image_databases.htm. There you should find something for your purposes.